# Having troubles with the queue module in python 3.9(snake game)

Tags: python

```
import pygame
import random
import queue

pygame.init()

#color values
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (213, 50, 80)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (50, 153, 213)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)

#resolution
diswidth = 600
disheight = 400

#window size and name
dis = pygame.display.set_mode((diswidth,disheight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

#snake variables
snakeblock = 10
snakespeed = 15

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

Q = queue.Queue(maxsize=10)

#fonts
font_style = pygame.font.SysFont("bahnschrift", 25)
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 35)

#score function
def yourscore(score):
    value = score_font.render(f"Score: {score}", True, yellow)
    dis.blit(value, [0, 0])

#function to add tail segments
def oursnake(snakeblock,snakelist):
    for x in snakelist:
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, black, [x[0], x[1], snakeblock, snakeblock])

#message function
def message(msg, color):
    mesg = font_style.render(msg, True, color)
    dis.blit(mesg, [diswidth/10, disheight/1.2])

#lots of things
def gameLoop():
    game_over = False
    game_close = False

    direction = (" ")

    x1 = diswidth / 2
    y1 = disheight / 2

    x1_change = 0
    y1_change = 0

    snakelist = []
    snakelenght = 1

    foodx = round(random.randrange(0, diswidth - snakeblock) / 10.0) * 10.0
    foody = round(random.randrange(0, disheight - snakeblock) / 10.0) * 10.0

#the main while loop
    while not game_over:
        #this is what happens if the snake collides with itself or with the walls
        while game_close == True:
            dis.fill(blue)
            pygame.HWSURFACE
            message("You lost! Press Q to quit or C to play again", red)

            pygame.display.update()

            #button mapings for game over screen
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        game_over = True
                        game_close = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()
        #keypresses
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over=True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and direction != "right":
                    Q.put("left")
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and direction != "left":
                    Q.put("right")
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and direction != "down":
                    Q.put("up")
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and direction != "up":
                    Q.put("down")
        if Q.empty() is False:
            if Q.get() == "left" and direction != "right":
                x1_change = -snakeblock
                y1_change = 0
                direction = "left"
            elif Q.get() == "right" and direction != "left":
                x1_change = snakeblock
                y1_change = 0
                direction = "right"
            elif Q.get() == "up" and direction != "down":
                x1_change = 0
                y1_change = -snakeblock
                direction = "up"
            elif Q.get() == "down" and direction != "up":
                x1_change = 0
                y1_change = -snakeblock
                direction = "down"
            pygame.display.update()
        if x1 >= diswidth or x1 < 0 or y1 >= disheight or y1 < 0:
            game_close = True

        #lots of things im too lazy to space out
        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change
        dis.fill(blue)
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, black, [x1,y1,snakeblock,snakeblock])
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, green, [foodx, foody, snakeblock, snakeblock])
        pygame.display.update()

        snakehead = []
        snakehead.append(x1)
        snakehead.append(y1)
        snakelist.append(snakehead)
        if len(snakelist) > snakelenght:
            del snakelist[0]
        for x in snakelist[:-1]:
            if x == snakehead:
                game_close = True

        oursnake(snakeblock, snakelist)
        yourscore(snakelenght - 1)
        pygame.display.update()

        #Eats food
        if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0, diswidth - snakeblock) / 10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(0, disheight - snakeblock) / 10.0) * 10.0
            snakelenght += 1
        clock.tick(snakespeed)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
gameLoop()
```

This is my code for my snake game.
I am having trouble with the queue module since whenever I try to input something it wont input, if I go and check the queue size it will update itself every tick if its empty but will stop once there is something in it.

I can only move left(other directions wont let me move) and when I press something after going left it stops in place and I have to terminate the program.

Idk if my code is the problem(probably) but if that's the case why does it let me move left and not any other direction.
Any help would be appreciated
Also, how can I make the framerate more smooth?

Comment: Have you tried to start the code in your debugger and step line by line through the code?

Comment: Please do not just dump 150 lines of barely structured code at people. See the [mcve] help page how to provide a *minimal* example.

Comment: It's unrelated to your current issue, but the queue objects from the `queue` module are intended for multithreaded communication, where you need locks and similar stuff to maintain consistency. If you just want a FIFO queue for a single-threaded application (or at least where only one thread is dealing with the data structure), you probably want to use `collections.deque` instead (which is what `queue.Queue` uses for its implementation).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm really sorry, first time posting here so thought that people needed to see the full code. I'll make sure to cut down on the code next time I post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you are consuming the queue on the first `if Q.get() == "left"` so the `elif Q.get() == "right"` is working on next item in queue which then most often is just empty.

Put the fetched item from the queue in an local variable before testing

```
next_command = Q.get()
if next_command == "left" and direction != "right":
    x1_change = -snakeblock
    y1_change = 0
    direction = "left"
elif next_command == "right" and direction != "left":
    x1_change = snakeblock
    y1_change = 0
    direction = "right"
elif next_command == "up" and direction != "down":
    ...
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks, but can you tell me how to make it so that only one "thing"(I forgot the terminology) can be executed per tick, so that the snake has time to move down before moving to the right if I press down and right really fast?

Comment: @Bisquit111 I'm sorry. I can't see anything obvious. Have actually never used pygame and don't have it installed so I can't test the code. Try remove as much code as possible while still seeing the problem. Maybe that helps and it makes it easier for others to help if you create a new question about your new problem

Comment: Its ok, again, thanks for the original comment. Someone else mentioned the other part and yea when I look at it now, 150 lines of code is too much